# proof by mathematical induction with the summation operator?

Tags: induction

$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n k \right)^2
$$
I can't  quite understand this expression, and in fact this is my biggest difficulty in finding a solution. Can someone please explain to me ?
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)} 2
$$

Comment: Left side is $1^3+2^3+\cdots+n^3$.  Right side is $(1+2+\cdots+n)^2$

Comment: I love this result: it's quite simple and looks like it should be wrong.

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/973456/prove-by-induction-sum-n3-sum-n2

Answer (score 1):

It's asking you to prove that the following identity holds for all $n \in \mathbb N$:
$$
1^3 + 2^3 + \cdots + n^3 = (1 + 2 + \cdots + n)^2
$$
For example, when $n = 5$, we have that:
$$
1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + 4^3 + 5^3 = 225 = (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)^2
$$

Comment: can you prove by math induction please?

Comment: @MatematikaMatematika: have you used induction previously?  What would be the base step?  How would the assumption step look?

Comment: i guess i prove for n=1 then we assume for n=k it's true and then by using this assumption we prove it for n=k+1

Comment: @MatematikaMatematika Have you already seen a closed form expression for $1 + 2 + \cdots + n$? That can help.

Comment: what about now?#

Answer (score 0):

you must prove that $1^3+2^3+...+n^3+(n+1)^3=(1+2+...+n+(n+1))^2$ and use that 
$1^3+2^3+...+n^3=(1+2+...+n)^2$ holds. Now you can write
$1^3+2^3+3^3+...+n^3+(n+1)^3=(1+2+...+n)^2+(n+1)^3$
in the next step we have to show that
$(1+2+...+n)^2+(n+1)^3=(1+2+...+n+(n+1))^2$

Comment: what about now if we have the below expression

Answer (score 0):

You have $S_n=1+...+n = {1 \over 2} n (n+1)$. This is straightforward to show.

Let $C_n = 1^3+... +n^3$.

You want to show $C_n = S_n^2$. It is true for $n=1$, so suppose it is true for $n$.

Then $C_{n+1} = C_n + n^3$.

Also, $S_{n+1}^2 = (S_n + (n+1))^2 = S_n^2 +2 S_n (n+1) + (n+1)^2$.

Note that $2 S_n (n+1) + (n+1)^2 = (n+1)^2 (n+1) = (n+1)^3 $.

Hence $ C_{n+1} = S_{n+1}^2$.